# JavaScript referencing an object in an argument

Tags: javascript, inheritance, reference, extend

Does JavaScript reference a global object anywhere in the code (function, object, etc)?

I have wrote this and it works as it works (written in inline-comments):

```
function Extender(object, property, value) {
    object[property] = value;
}

var MyObject = {};

MyObject.zlatan = 'at stackoverflow';

console.log(MyObject.zlatan); // at stackoverflow

// -----

Extender(MyObject, "stackoverflow", function() {
    return console.log('I am executing MyObject.stackoverflow()');
});

MyObject.stackoverflow(); // I am executing MyObject.stackoverflow()
```

Extender function, as you see, takes three arguments, and with it I can add new properties and their values (strings, numerics, arrays, objects, function callbacks, etc).

One of my questions here is also why don't we need any special pointer/identifier for a referencing variable, like we do in PHP:

```
$something &= $somethingElse;
```

or in a PHP function/method:

```
function something( &$argument ) {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Because this is not PHP :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables in JavaScript are references.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables !!!!